# Pagination does not work in unless the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, web, laravel-livewire

If I click on "next", the page does not show up unless I refresh it.

I don't understand why I am using Laravel and liveware.

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Cart;

class ShopComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function store($product_id, $product_name, $product_price)
    {
        Cart::add($product_id, $product_name, 1, $product_price) - > associate('App\Models\Product');
        session() - > flash('success_message', 'Item added in cart');

        return redirect() - > route('product.cart');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(12);

        return view('livewire.shop-component', ['products' => $products]) - > layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no personal livewire development experience, but your code doesn't look like it is is complete and reproducible to me.  It looks like it would been a list of products defined somewhere to be able to run it.

Comment: Could you post your `shop-component.blade.php` also? And, what's up with your arrows? They should be attached: `)->`